# How to load angular-social-auth module for the specific component

Tags: angular, authentication, npm

I'm using angular2-social-auth module for facebook and google login and module in the main app module, Everything working fine. But the issue is angular-social-auth module effecting to the other component (dashboard component, profile component etc) loading issue.(**Note:** All the component have one main app module) My question is, **IS there a way to restrict the angular-social-auth module for the login component only.**

### Main app module

```
    import { NgModule }from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Angular2SocialLoginModule } from "angular2-social-login";
    import { DashboardComponent } from components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
    import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';


    let providers = {
        "google": {
          "clientId": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
        },
        "facebook": {
          "clientId": "FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID",
          "apiVersion": "<version>" //like v2.4 
        }
      };

    @NgModule({
     declarations: [
      DashboardComponent,
      ProfileComponent
    ],
      imports: [ 
                  BrowserModule,
                  Angular2SocialLoginModule
              ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })

   export class AppModule { 
      constructor(){}
    }

    Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```